# Android MediaCodec releaseOutputBuffer throws MediaCodec.CodecException when decoding H264 video

Tags: android, video, decode, android-mediacodec

I am using `MediaCodec` API to decode a H264 video stream using a `SurfaceView` as the output surface. The decoder is configured successfully without any errors. When I try to finally render the decoded video frame onto the `SurfaceView` using `releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, true)`, it throws `MediaCodec.CodecException`, however the video is rendered correctly.

Calling `getDiagnosticInfo()` and `getErrorCode()` on the exception object return an error code of -34, but I can't find in the docs what this error code means. The documentation is also very unclear about when this exception is thrown.

Has anyone faced this exception/error code before? How can I fix this?

PS: Although the video works fine but this exeception is thrown at every`releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, true),` call.

Answer (score 1):

Android media-codec is very dependant on the device vendor. Samsung is incredibly problematic other devices running the same code will run fine. This has been my life for the last 6 months.

The best approach to do although it can feel wrong is to try + catch + retry. There are 4 distinct places where the MediaCodec will throw exceptions:

1. Configuration - NativeDecoder.Configure(...);
2. Start - NativeDecoder.Start();
3. Render output - NativeDecoder.ReleaseOutputBuffer(...);
4. Input - codec.QueueInputBuffer(...);

NOTE: my code is in Xamarin but the calls map very closely to raw java.

The way you configure your format description also matters. The media-codec can crash on NEXUS devices if you don't specify:

```
formatDescription.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyMaxInputSize, currentPalette.Width * currentPalette.Height);
```

When you catch any exception you will need to ensure the mediacodec is reset. Unfortunatly reset isnt available to older api-levels but you can simulate the same effect with:

```
    #region Close + Release Native Decoder

    void StopAndReleaseNativeDecoder() {
        FlushNativeDecoder();
        StopNativeDecoder();
        ReleaseNativeDecoder();
    }

    void FlushNativeDecoder() {
        if (NativeDecoder != null) {
            try {
                NativeDecoder.Flush();
            } catch {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }

    void StopNativeDecoder() {
        if (NativeDecoder != null) {
            try {
                NativeDecoder.Stop();
            } catch {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }

    void ReleaseNativeDecoder() {
        while (NativeDecoder != null) {
            try {
                NativeDecoder.Release();
            } catch {
                // ignore
            } finally {
                NativeDecoder = null;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Once you catch the error when you pass new input you can check:

```
if (!DroidDecoder.IsRunning && streamView != null && streamView.VideoLayer.IsAvailable) {
        DroidDecoder.StartDecoder(streamView.VideoLayer.SurfaceTexture);
}

DroidDecoder.DecodeH264FrameBuffer(payload, payloadSize, frameDuration, presentationTime, isKeyFrame);
```

Rendering to a texture-view seems to be the most stable option currently. But the device fragmentation has really hurt android in this area. We have found cheaper devices such as a the Tesco Hudl to be of the most stable for video. Even had up to 21 concurrent videos on screen at 1 time. Samsung S4 can get around 4-6 depending on the resolution/fps but something like the HTC can work as well as the Hudl. Its been a wake up call and made me realise samsung devices are literally copying apple design and twiddling with the android-sdk and actually breaking a lot of functionality along the way.

Comment: @redbain I agree with your observations. Samsung is generally the most unstable. They completely broke their OpenMAX implementation in Android 5.0.

Comment: In my case MediaCodec exception is thrown at every ReleaseOutputBuffer call. So I don't think restarting the decoder after every frame is an option.

Comment: @nangal.vivek are you parsing out NALU segments? You must parse our nalu segments in your stream and make sure they are in annexb format. which is 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,<nalu-segment>. Might be the issue. I dont know if you can use media-extractor for this in my case we are parsing a real-time network feed.

Answer (score -1):

It is most probably an issue with the codec you are using. Try using something like this to

```
private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mime){
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < numCodecs;  i++){
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        if(!codecInfo.isEncoder()){
            continue;
        }

        String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
        for(int j = 0; j < types.length; j++){
            if(types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mime)){
                return codecInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then setting your encoder with:

```
MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
mEncoder = MediaCodec.createCodecByName(codecInfo.getName());
```

That may resolve your error by ensuring that the Codec you've chosen is fully supported.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is there anything that can be inferred from the error code -34?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I can find. You may need to look through the source of MediaCodec to find where -34 is thrown inside that code.